# Pass tableviewcell data with segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a popover segue that goes to a view controller. I want to set some properties in the view controller when a cell is clicked. I tried using `-prepareForSegue:`, but then I realized that it doesn't have the scope of the selected cell. I know that I have to use:

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 delegate method, but I'm not sure how that will affect the popover segue. Do I have to programatically create the popover, or is there another way?

Thanks much!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add an NSIndexPath propriety to your VC. Let's call it selectedCell. In your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, save the selected index path to the instance variable.

Then in your prepareForSegue method, use the instance variable.

Alternately, in your prepareForSegue method, you could ask the table view for the currently selected row using the table view's indexPathForSelectedRow method.

Answer (score 3):

Use `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` to get the data from your table's data source, e.g., the array backing the table data. If, for some reason, you don't want to get the data from your data source, then the `sender` is the `UITableViewCell` that was tapped to trigger the segue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueID"]) {
        YourDestinationViewControllerClass* destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationController.somePublicProperty = self.yourTablesDataSourceArray[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
        destinationController.someOtherPublicProperty = cell.textLabel.text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use the `indexPathForSelectedRow` property.
For example you can write a code like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [sender indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NextViewController *vc = (NextViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.yourProperty = @"Some Value";
    }
}
```

Assuming `NextViewController` as your segue destination controller and `yourProperty` as the property you want to set during the segue, you can access and set information from your  parent controller because `indexPathForSelectedRow` automatically knows which cell has been clicked.
More information can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow).